# Iam trying to import the PyAutoGUI module but iam getting an error

Tags: pyautogui

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a:\Prank python\prank_wa.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PyAutoGUI as pt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyAutoGUI'
```

I am trying to import the ModuleNotFoundError  but its throuing me an error please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm assuming you have `pyautogui` installed, which you can do with:

`pip install pyautogui`

Anyways, the reason you are having this issue is because you are not importing the module with the correct name. It should be `pyautogui`, not `PyAutoGUI`, no uppercase letters. Now try it:

`import pyautogui`

And it should work, pretty simple fix. (Idk why pypi.org shows the module name as PyAutoGUI).